# How to Pass index 1 to index 0 Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop, rxjs

How do you set 0 index value in my setItem instead of 1 index.

here you need to fill up the qty before you open the dialog then try to type anything and submit it it will go to the index 1 instead of 0

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-x4e1is)

> this is my child component which is inside in the dialog box

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
      id: [],
      Name:['', Validators.required],
      qty:[0, Validators.required],
      arrayForm: this.fb.array([this.CreateArray()]),
    });
    this.form.get('qty').valueChanges.subscribe((res) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < res; i++) {
        this.displayArray.push(this.CreateArray());
        console.log(res);
      }
    });

 CreateArray(){
    return this.fb.group({
      qtyRow: ['',Validators.required]
    });
  }

onSave(){  
    this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value)
  }
```

here is my parent component that will pass the data to the afterclosed result

```
openDialogChildComponent(index: number){
  let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ChildComponent, {
    autoFocus: false,
      maxHeight: '90vh', //you can adjust the value as per your view
    data:{
      qty:this.form.value[index].qty
    }
  })
  
  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.arrayForm.length; i++) {
      this.SArray.push(this.qtyRow(result.arrayForm[i].qtyRow));
    }
    });
}

  this.Form = this.formBuilder.group({
      id : [0],
      Details:['']
      SArray: this.formBuilder.array([this.CreateQtyRow('')])
    })


CreateQtyRow(data): FormGroup {
    
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      NameData:[data]
    })
  }
```

Comment: where is index 1 instead of 0 ?

Comment: @Zerotwelve in my parent component i want to send it to my parent component once i submit it on my dialog and it shown index 1 instead of index 0

Comment: `qty:this.form.value[index].qty` this `index` is 1 instead of 0 ? or where exactly?

Comment: wait let me give you my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-x4e1is here you need to fill up the qty before you open the dialog then try to type anything and submit it it will go to the index 1 instead of 0

Comment: do you mean that in the "setItem" list it will be added in the second position?
this is because you have an array with one item at start, and then you push more items in the array, of course it will be added at index 1. index 0 is already filled and you push new elements in...

Comment: @Zerotwelve how to fix that?